# In a HTML email signature is there way to conditionally hide content?

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I have created a HTML email signature that uses variables to get data from active directory, but if any of these variables are empty the signature displays a blank space.

Is there any way - preferably without javascript (if possible) - to say if the variable is empty/null then don't display that line of content.

For example, if the email field is empty the signature will display 'E: [blank space]'.  I'd rather it not display the Email line.  The images are probably more helpful.

Here is the code [snippet] I'm using in the signature...

```
<div class="all-info" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;padding-top: 15px">
   <h3 style="margin: 0px; color: #DB0E15">%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%</h3>
   <h4 style="margin: 0px; padding: 3px 0px 6px 0px;">%%title%%</h4>
   <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><span style="color: #DB0E15">E : </span>%%email%%</h5>
   <h5 style="margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 3px;"><span style="color: #DB0E15">T : </span>%%PhoneNumber%%</h5>
</div>
```

Note: It needs to work in Outlook as well as other clients/browsers.

Signature when email not blank

[image]

Signature with blank email - don't want this line appearing

[image]

Comment: You appear to have written your own template system to replace the variables? Then extend it to conditionally hide blocks. You can't run JavaScript in an email, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's the bit I'm asking for help with.

Comment: @CodeCaster see my [not an] answer below

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. The percent-variables are a built-in feature of Outlook. This question may therefore be a better fit on SuperUser instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, but I maybe should've mentioned that the signature was being applied in/through Exchange Admin. Apologies.

So, should I (re)submit it to SuperUser as you suggest?